# Opencv produces many valgrind errors

Tags: c++, opencv, valgrind

I have a most simple C++ application that displays a photo using OpenCV:

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread("photo.jpg");
    cv::imshow("image", img);
    cv::waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

...and I compile it on linux, gcc 7.2.0 against OpenCV 3.2.0 (ubuntu repository version) like this:

```
$ g++ -c -o example_opencv.o example_opencv.cpp
$ g++ -o example_opencv example_opencv.o -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_highgui
```

The program obviously works without any problems. However, it produces an *insane* amount of errors when checked by Valgrind:

```
$ valgrind ./example_opencv
(... lengthy error report ...)
==14665== LEAK SUMMARY:
==14665==    definitely lost: 34,152 bytes in 434 blocks
==14665==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14665==      possibly lost: 1,024 bytes in 14 blocks
==14665==    still reachable: 64,144 bytes in 1,328 blocks
==14665==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14665== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==14665== 
==14665== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==14665== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==14665== ERROR SUMMARY: 105422 errors from 1000 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

If I use the same approach on a program with real memory-related bugs, its errors would get completely lost within this mess.

Is there any chance do debug OpenCV programs using Valgrind?

Comment: Why don't you do what the tool is telling you to do, namely "==14665== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==14665== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from"

Comment: I don't mind the leaked memory, I'm more concerned about the 105422 errors. Most of them are `Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)`. The origins are mostly `libstdc++.so` and `libc-2.28.so`, nothing interesting there.